# Issue Performing Mathematical Operations on Money Objects - "Unknown Method "exchange_to" for 0:fixnum" [Rails 4] [Money Gem]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, money-rails

I currently have the money gem installed via `money-rails` and it's working great. I have a monetized object called `:default_price` and `:default_price_cents` and am using a `:currency` column to define the currencies. I also have a `:default_packs` column which is a user defined integer that's monetized, and a Pack model which stores a new entry every day with a `:date` column and a `:amount` column.

Here's my **user.rb**

```
  has_many :packs

  register_currency :usd

  monetize :default_price_cents, with_model_currency: :currency
  monetize :default_price, with_model_currency: :currency
  monetize :daily_saving_potential, with_model_currency: :currency
  monetize :total_saving_potential, with_model_currency: :currency
  monetize :total_money_spent, with_model_currency: :currency
  monetize :total_savings, with_model_currency: :currency

  def daily_saving_potential
    return default_price * default_packs
  end

  def total_saving_potential
    days = self.packs.count
    return days * daily_saving_potential
  end

  def total_money_spent
    amount = self.packs.map(&:amount).sum
    return amount
  end

  def total_savings
    return total_saving_potential - total_money_spent
  end
```

**The Problem**

`total_money_spent` sums all the entries of the :amount field from my Pack model. The problem arises that when `total_savings` is called upon in my view, I get an error saying **`Unknown Method "exchange_to" for 0:fixnum`**.

The interesting thing is that if I use `:default_price_cents` instead of `:default_price` in `daily_saving_potential`, then I don't get the error, but my custom defined fields in the model display the default currency instead of the currency defined by the user, whereas the `default_price` field displays the right currency defined by the user. Perhaps the issue has to do with the fact that I'm multiplying money objects with a non-money object from my Pack model? Regardless, the issue arises when I subtract the `total_money_spent` from `total_saving_potential`

Let me know if you need more information, and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't worked with this gem, but it doesn't look like you've followed the read-me for the money-rails gem

https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails

Assuming you have a field in the model `:default_price_cents` you can do...

```
  monetize :default_price_cents, with_model_currency: :currency
```

... and this will automatically give you a monetzed field called ':default_price`.  You don't need to define it and you don't need to "monetize" it, it's already a money attribute.

Similarly, you should be creating methods called `daily_saving_potential_cents` and `total_saving_potential_cents` and `total_money_spent_cents` etc etc etc. You will automatically have a method `daily_saving_potential`, and `total_saving_potential` and so on.

In your method calculations use the raw (.._cents) attributes.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for the advice. I will take a look at it in the morning.

Comment: This worked perfectly! I must be more thorough in reading the readme. Thank you Steve.